# asp.net create new instance of page on login

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, instance

I have a log in page and a page that displays data to the user. Currently when multiple users log into my website they all see what the other users have done to the graphs on the second page.

I was wondering if someone could point me to some tutorials or inform me on how to make it so that when the user logs in they see a new instance of the second graph page every time and that any data they change doesn't show on other user sessions?

I did not use forms authentication for login, I simply made a custom login entry and connect it to a database which has the user login information stored in it. The users in this database are created through a separate program which are then updated to the database.

The data that is displayed on the second graph page is unique to each user as certain users only have access to certain data. This causes problems when multiple users log in as they are able to see information displayed from other currently logged in users. This information that is being displayed is also coming from a database, the database is populated with data from another application.

Comment: Before posting some very generic tutorials on accessing user identity and session data, can you provide these details: 1) Did you use the Forms Authentication login or another method? How was the user created? 2) How is the data unique to each user? Is it coming from a database? In short: more details would help make the answer useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since figured out how to deal with this. I have posted other questions as I have worked my way through learning about sessions. I thought I might post links to them here in case anyone is ever in the same situation.

[asp.net Create new Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006717/asp-net-create-new-session)