# asp.net Create new Session

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a website that a user signs into and then access a second page with data relevant to that user. So far I have got it working that when the user logs there userID and username is saved into a session. The problem is when multiple users sign in they overwrite each others session.

```
string testusername = Session["UserName"] + ""; //Session data for username and user ID
string testuserid = Session["UserID"] + "";
```

Basically what I am trying to figure out is how to create a new session for each user or if there is another method that would allow me store the username and userID in such a way that only the website will know who to send what information to.

Comment: Session are created automatically.  Are you testing the different users from the same browser?

Comment: "The problem is when multiple users sign in they overwrite each others session." - Then the sessions are broken, or are being used incorrectly. Sessions are and should be *per* user (really, per browser/session cookie). So where does `Session` come from in this case?

Comment: @BlackFrog I have tested across different browsers and on different machines. Which was what made me think I have done something done somwehere.
@user2864740 My knowledge of `Session` is very limited. I have just used it as is. Is there something I have missed which I need to do in order to create a new session each time? Feel free to point me to some tutorials I have looked around but am struggling to find some decent ones.

Comment: You need to test each user in a different browser when testing locally. That is: one user on IE, one Firefox, One on chrome simulaneously. That should result in 3 seperate sessions. Multiple instances of the same browser or tabs **won't** work. I also suggest reading this: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured out my problem, it was my mistake. I was not telling the website that the information that was being displayed had anything to do with the session. In the end I added something similar to the code below.

```
sqlCompleted.SelectCommand = Session["SessionsqlCompleted"] + "";
```

This then made the sql saved with each session so now the data that is displayed is relevant to each session. I apologize I realised once after a few days that I had thought about this completely the wrong way.

Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Session.Clear()` or `Session.Abandon()` method to clear out/reset the session variable

When you log out the website